# How to login with touch id in aws cognito?

Tags: ionic-framework, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, touch-id

I have to login the mobile application with touchID/fingerprint using aws cognito. I am not able to find any defined methods for that in aws cognito.

Thanks in advance